# referencing cell of matrix that was not created through list comprehension

Tags: python, matrix

I have a dynamic matrix and I wish to change the values in one of the cells. The catch is, i sort of hard-coded the matrix as it is made up of separate lists (not a nested list) that are printed one after another.

I know my life would be a lot easier if I used list comprehension or even NumPy instead but I would like to know if there's a solution to change values that don't use anything nested or imported.

```
rows = int(input("number of rows "))
columns = int(input("number of columns "))


row_1 = ["0"] * (columns)
row_2 = ["0"] * (columns)
row_3 = ["0"] * (columns)
row_4 = ["0"] * (columns)


if rows >= 1:
    print(row_1)

if rows >= 2:
    print(row_2)

if rows >= 3:
    print(row_3)

if rows >= 4:
    print(row_4)

# Change value in certain row and column
value = input("enter value")
rows = int(input("Row number "))
columns = int(input("Column number "))

# At this part the cell in the user-selected row and column is changed to inputted value
# but I'm not sure how to do it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the user's indexing, you must have your lists connected in a sequence.  Yes, you *could* go through some nasty hoops to generate a variable name from user input, but that is *very* bad programming practice.

```
master_list = [row_1, row_2, row_3, row_4]
master_list[rows][columns] = value
```

Yes, this is a nested structure.  You designed a nested concept, you're taking input that implies a nested structure.  If you have a salient objection to solving this with nesting, please clarify that point.